Isotopy of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$ fixing the boundary
Let $\varphi: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be an homeomorphism of the disk $\mathbb{D} := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \leq 1 \}$
that fixes de boundary $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1 \}$
and has a fixed point $z_0$.
How can I show that it is isotopic to another homeomorphism that is identity in a small disk around $z_0$, with all the homeomorphisms in the isotopy fixing the boundary too?
I think I can suposse $z_0 = 0$.
I have seen a proof that might help Isotopy to the identity on disk.
It proves that $\varphi $ is isotopic to the identity.

Nevermind, the link solves it.
